# Custom grid for ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-grid

I'm implementing a ASP.NET MVC 2 application and I need a grid with the following features:

- Editable fields, with templaes (e.g. numeric field, date picker, dynamic drop-down combo).
- Add rows in the client side (no callback) by pressing a button/link.
- Remove rows in the cliente side (no callback) by pressing a button/link.
- Add rows in the client side when tab is pressed in the last editable column (no callback).
- Control the name of the input controls (so they are posted with those names on form submition).
- Have some non-editable columns whose value is calculated in the client side (no callback) depending on other columns' values.

E.g.: I'll use it for a `Order -> IList<OrderLine>` (one to many) Model.

I was planning to develop it myself using jQuery but I don't want to re-invent the wheel. Is there any javascript framework which already privides such a grid?

---

**Update:** I've tried [Telerik grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid), but found it difficult to get all the features mentioned above. So, any advice from experienced Telerik users about how to implement all of them with that extension is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out telerik Extensions for asp.net MVC , i think they have what you are looking for

Comment: no i think its open sourced , or an opensource version ,check it out

Answer (score 2):

Check out MVC Contrib, http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/releases

Answer (score 1):

Do you know this site:

[www.datatables.net](http://www.datatables.net/)

I have used this plugin a year ago and from what I remember most of your requirements can be done. It is free.